# @ModelAttribute not works when a declared field is left blank

Tags: html, spring-mvc, controller, spring-roo

Below are my code...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submitnewstory", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String save(@ModelAttribute("storyInsertForm") StoryInsertForm uploadForm, HttpSession session, Model map) {
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<form:form id="contentForm" class="cssform2" action="submitnewstory" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" modelAttribute="storyInsertForm">

</form:form>
```

**What is happening??**

Suppose I have two fields in my model (in this case `StoryInsertForm`) i.e. `String firstname` and `String lastname`. I have to declare the same variable within the `<form:form>`, Something like the following

```
<form:form id="contentForm" class="cssform2" action="submitnewstory" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" modelAttribute="storyInsertForm">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" />
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" />
</form:form>
```

What is happening is that if you give a value to the first input and ignore the second one the data doesn't even reach the controller. But if you provide all the values, i.e. provide input to both input type text, it finds the controller and everything works just fine.

Another observation says that if you do not declare one of the field, i.e. something like the following :

```
<form:form id="contentForm" class="cssform2" action="submitnewstory" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" modelAttribute="storyInsertForm">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" />
<!--    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" /> -->
</form:form>
```

the data still gets posted with the data provided in the above field (in this case firstname).

**Summary**

If you have associated the fields in the html you have to enter some values in the input type or else nothing reaches the controller.

Looking forward to your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think,

You have to bind the form input tags also for using

the Spring Form TagLib.

i.e.

```
<form:form id="contentForm" class="cssform2" action="submitnewstory" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" modelAttribute="storyInsertForm">
    <form:input  path="firstname" id="firstname" />
    <form:input  path="lastname" id="lastname" />
</form:form>
```

Also I do not know what your controller coding is, So I think below points are worth to mention -

1>  in the function where the page is returned as RequestMethod GET, add a model attribute for the form.

In this case, Full coding should be -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getpage.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getPage(Model model){
        ........
        Other Code Snippet
        .........

    StoryInsertForm uploadForm = new StoryInsertForm();
    model.addAttribute(“storyInsertForm”,  uploadForm);
    return “login”;
}
```

2> Also  Add the BindingResult parameter to data save method, otherwise you should get an exception -

So the code for save method should be -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submitnewstory", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String save(@ModelAttribute("storyInsertForm") StoryInsertForm uploadForm, BindingResult result,  HttpSession session, Model map) {
     ...........
     Your Save Business Logic and Other DAO Method call etc...
     ...........
}
```

I Hope, the above code should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem; I could not solve it but could circumvent it by using

```
<form></form>
```

instead of

```
 <form:form></form:form>
```

Hope it helps!